# CodeIgniter login to multiple domains

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, authentication

I have a CI website (http://www.abc.com). Now we are setting up another domain pointing to the same code for different language (http://www.abc.com.cn).

the thing is when switch to another site after logging in to .com, i am not logged in at .com.cn.

in the login controller, i check the url and curl to another domain to set the sessions. but it looks like it doesn't work.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using session, please use cookie.

and then in your login code. you have to manually loop thru all of your site url to set logged in cookie domain.

```
foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    $this->input->set_cookie(array('name' => 'name', 'value' => 'logged-in', 'expire' => 86500, 'domain' => $domain));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a codeigniter problem. It's a common web application problem. The solution you're looking for is [federated authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity). That is, a third party is responsible for the login and credentials validation part.

For example, the StackExchange network uses [OpenId](http://openid.net/) to allow you to login to its multiple domains and subdomains.

One workaround would be to implement one of the available F.A. systems (like Open ID or Facebook Connect for example) on both sites if you do not want to create and maintain an identity server but you can, see the [documentation for OpenId](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995226/Run%20your%20own%20identity%20server).